# Vue.js computed property to parse/format data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get a Vue.js computed property to do some reconfiguring of data and when I do it inside the computed property I get an error about side effects. I looked it up on here and found that using a method is the correct way of doing this. Now when trying to use a method it results in error messages in the console about it can't read the property of 'units' from selectedBuilding.

What I am trying to figure out is how to have it so the units array is populated with the correct data depending on the computed return value

Below is the code stripped down for the script section of my Vue.js file.

```
export default {
  name: "Form",
  data: () => ({
    building: {},
    buildings: [
      {
        "units": [ //  Bunch of data in here that isn't important//],
        "buildingID": "<an ID according to a custom format>",
    }],
    units: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    formatUnits: function(selectedBuildingID) {
      let selectedBuilding = this.buildings.find(building => building.buildingID === selectedBuildingID)
      this.units = selectedBuilding.units
      return true
    }
  },
  computed: {
        useExistingBuilding() {
      if(this.building === 'New') {return true}
      else {
        this.formatUnits(this.building)
        return false
      }
        },
    }
};
</script>
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'units' of undefined
```

Comment: Are you sure that  the `find` in `this.building.find` actually returns a valid value? it might be that it doesn't exists

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza yes 100% sure it returns something.I can console.log the value when using just the computed and it works perfectly fine except the side effects error

Answer (score 0):

Since `this.building` has no `buildingID` (thus, `undefined`), and there is no item in `buildings` that has `undefined` as the value for `buildingID`, it fails.

This is because the find method will return `undefined` when the condition couldn't be satisfied.

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: I don't think you are right, I might have trimmed down the data wrong but it does 100% have a buildingID. I can console.log it and see it.

Comment: Well, AFIAK, it's ID is not in `buildings` can you show us (i.e. update the question) your example data? The one that works?

Answer (score 0):

In the computed property you are passing the whole `building` rather than the id, whereas in your method (in `find`) you are comparing the ids.

You need to pass the building id to your method.

Also in your `data` you are declaring `building` as an object, and then in your computed property, you are asserting whether `building` equals `New` which is a string.

I would advise the first thing you have to do is rethink your data types and the flow of your data between the template, computed properties, methods and data.

Comment: Good catch on the data type mix-match, I don't think that is the actual issue since the eval seems to work fine, I have a v-select in the template that sets building to either a string of 'New' or an object. Adding the buildingID to the place where I call the method seems to have resolved the console issue and allowed me to render the page. Still not working as I want but progress.

Comment: Well I marked that solved too soon the data it is sending is undefined. When I `console.log(this.building)` it gives the building ID because that is what my select returns back.

Comment: I did a couple console.log to see what things return `selectedBuildingID` is returning an ID fine. `selectedBuilding` is returning an object which is fine. However when I do `selectedBuilding.units` it says it can't find units of undefined

Comment: if selectedBuilding is undefined it meand the find method is not working, which means the data you are checking inside of find is not what you think it is.... try to log ```this.buildingd``` and the ```selectedBuildingID``` just before the find method to see what they hold